# Concat Variable in template kendo grid Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to next in the template using kendo ui grid  jquery

```
 #for (var i=1; i<=7 ; i++){#
                <td>
               <div>
                    <span> #:Ros# </span>
                    <span> #:Rost#  </span>
                </div>

            </td>
         # } #
```

what I try to concatenate using the counter for example: Ros1 Rost1 - Ros2 Rost2 - Ros3 Rost3.. etc 
there is the possibility of concat the Ros and Rost with the counter i  " Ros+i Rost+i"

Answer (score 0):

Templates like data, even if there is no data.  You should pass an empty array when there is no data for the template.

```
<table>
  <tr id="templateResolved">
  </tr>
<table>

<script id="myCells" type="type/x-kendo-template">
  # for (var i=1; i<=7 ; i++) { #
      <td>
        <div>
          <span> Ros#:i# </span>
          <span> Rost#:i# </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    # } #
</script>

<script>
  var templateSourceCode = $("#myCells").html();
  var templateCompiled = kendo.template(templateSourceCode);
  var templateResolved = templateCompiled([]);  // <-------------- pass in empty array

  $("#templateResolved").html(templateResolved);
</script>
```